# emacs org-babel-tangle: ensure relative path of links in tangled comments

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I'm using emacs 25.3.1 with Org mode version 9.1.9. I'm trying to ensure that the comments produced by the `org-babel-tangle` function and preceding the source block content in the tangled file contain the relative path to the original org file and not the absolute path. Although the [documentation](https://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html) states that the `org-babel-tangle-use-relative-file-links` variable, which defaults to `t`, ensures this precise behaviour, I keep getting the absolute path in the links (e.g. `# [[file:~/Projects/my_project/my_project.org::*setup.py][setup.py:1]]`).

I tried setting this variable to `nil` but it didn't change anything. When manually changing the links with the relative path ( e.g. `# [[file:../my_project.org::*setup.py][setup.py:1]]`), invoking `org-babel-detangle` to integrate changes to the tangled file back to the original org file actually worked (with an additional interaction in the mini-buffer: `No match - create this as a new heading? (y or n)`).

Is there any way to get this relative path automatically from `org-babel-tangle` or is this a bug? This is a fairly important question if you think about projects with several contributors to a version controlled repository where

1. not everybody uses org-mode
2. obviously not everybody's working copy is located at the same absolute path on its own computer.

Comment: If the links are in org comments, they will not be touched: you will have to make them part of the document.

Comment: Sorry @Nick, I don't see what you mean. Can you elaborate a bit more. I'm talking about the comments in the tangled source file automatically generated by `org-babel-tangle` when the `comments` header argument of the corresponding src block is set to `link`.

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood. Please disregard.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. The calculation of `result` in ob-tangle.el is suspect in multiple ways AFAICS. Please report it to the org-mode ML.

Comment: @Pheidippides if possible, could you try this again on latest org-mode, from git? I just submitted a patch that fixes a related issue.